# How can a front-end be built for SPARQL from protege?

Tags: frontend, sparql, owl, protege

I have a Design Course Ontology. I want to create a frontend with just one search bar. The back end should contain SPARQL Query that I'm using in Protege 5.2

Comment: That's pretty much to broad for Stackoverflow! You can use anything, HTML, Java, C, Qt, anything can be used as GUI and then be backed by the application logic.

Comment: I'm from an electronics background and completely new to all this. Could you suggest a suitable path for this ? I'm well equipped with C language alone

Comment: You could use C# then for the GUI + the DotNetRDF API (http://www.dotnetrdf.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too broad.

If I understand right what you want; you need to build a user interface that interacts with a SPARQL engine, sends queries and receives results.

If this is what you want, there are multiple options.

**Microsoft**

1. I am not really aware of Microsoft (c(++)/c#) tools to query RDF with SPARQL, however, a simple googling results [dot net RDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/).

**Java:**

2. Simplest thing is having an RDF file containing your data, and using Jena (a java library) to query it. See [Jena ARQ for SPARQL](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/index.html), [SPARQL Tutorial](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_datasets.html) and [An Introduction to RDF](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html).
3. The other way around is using jena with some RDF native database storage. For example, you can use Jena with ([Graph DB](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/)), which has an endpoint that you can send queries and receive results from using [`sparqlservice`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/sparql-remote.html). This, however, would rather be complicated for your purposes.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want. Will try one of these methods. Thanks a lot !

Comment: How should I create the user interface ?

Comment: too broad again. I think you need at least: a. input area for entering the query (text), and b. an area to show the results. This could be done in multiple ways, and depends on the technology you use. Simply google GUI for the programming language you use,

Comment: I'm using the Jena Fuseki server that runs my SPARQL queries. It has the input area for entering the query and opens a separate window to show the results. How do I create a user interface that links to this?

Comment: Check out the example here to communicate from Java with the server https://gist.github.com/thiloplanz/f2d279cfc0880327a197